# Introducing SlimSharp

Tags: discussion, languages

[SlimSharp](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/SlimSharp) is a custom variant of C# intended to help with some of the worst pain points when using C# for Code Golf. It's something I've had in the back of my head for a while, and I finally took the time today to get it "on paper", at least in a digital sense. <strike>However, so far that's the *only* way it exists; there is no implementation.</strike>

SlimSharp won't keep up with some of the dedicated Code Golf or simple stack-based languages, but it should help reduce byte/character counts relative to other traditional languages.

My goal listing it here is so if I use it in an answer others will be able to verify the program is correct (spot bugs and improvements, etc), even if they have to evaluate the code in their heads, and so we can compare apples-to-apples if others can want to use the same "shortcuts".

**Update:** There is an implementation now, of sorts, and it is possible to run SlimSharp code. You can even [try it on .Net Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DkPEcu)

Comment: This sounds really interesting. I bet it'd be trivial to implement SlimSharp in Dyalog APL, and that'd also give you access to all of APL's power and conciseness.

Comment: the problem I have with languages like these, is that they are *between* a general purpose language and a language made completely for code golf. You lose the respect you would get from making a short answer in a general purpose language, but it still might not be competitive with CG langs that go all in.

Comment: @Wezl Very true. But no one is stopping you from doing the same kind of work for, say, Java or C. And if _that_ happens, then we start really being able to compare the languages more, rather than having things like the longer `Console` text throwing an answer for one language or another.

Comment: Some similar languages: [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), [Mthmtca](https://github.com/LegionMammal978/Mthmtca)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I do believe [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer) is a better language than my own silly attempt.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I personally don’t believe that these kind of posts (this and the ThumbGolf one) are on-topic for meta, and so I’ve downvoted both because of that, not because I dislike the languages. I think this post shows that allowing these kind of posts on Meta will lead to every new language having a new post, this cluttering Meta. There are many better ways to announce a new language, including posting in chat, the Showcase post and just answering challenges with that language.